How can i measure the output and input impedance of transistor in rf amplifier?
I built a circuit on 1 2sc3355 transistor, and i cant really find any information about how to measure/calculate or at least approximate the value output impedance of transistor. This circuit is for 25Mhz.
My main issue in this circuit is the output impedance of the transistor, to match to the next, higher power transistor. But to do that i have to know the input impedance of the next transistor as well.

(Image Source: https://www.rfcandy.biz/communication/pa313.html)
So if i would want to use that circuit, how can i get the input/output impedances of the transistor?

The first circuit (small signal stage) can be measured with a network analyzer. The amp needs a redesign. For the second circuit, the actual power amplifier, start at the output by calculating first, depending on the wanted output power, the optimal load for the transistor incl. a suitable impedance matching network with 50 Ohm output. The input impedance (R-jX) at the base is typ. low with BJT power amps. Compensate first  through measurement or simulation the capacitive component and devise a network to match the remaining resistive component to a 50 Ohm source impedance.

The usual way to do this is with a network analyzer. You essentially measure the RF reflection coefficients looking into the input and into the output and calculate the impedance from them.
If you are "measuring" the impedance in a simulator rather than on a real circuit, you can essentially simulate the network analyzer. Connect a 50-ohm AC source to one port. Terminate the other port with 50 ohms. Measure the response at the input port as an AC voltage signal. From that figure out what the reflection coefficient must be. From that calculate the port impedance.
Since both ports are AC-coupled it should be very straightforward because you have no worries about the test source messing up the bias point (particularly on the output impedance measurement).

So just stick the nanoVNA to the output of this circuit?

@edziograczer I'm not familiar with the nanoVNA. Is it a two port NA or one port? If it's two ports, connect one to the input and one to the output, and look at the S11 and S22 measurements. If it's a one port NA, then terminate the unconnected port with 50 ohms and connect the VNA to the port you want to measure.

Forget it. The 2nd circuit is highly nonlinear r.f. output stage. It's so nonlinear that concept impedance is totally meaningless for the transistor. The load and the feeding signal source may have them, but not the transistor. Better to estimate the functionality by making time domain simulations (a.k.a. transient analysis). AC analysis is useless. Simulation can be used also to find good component values by trial and error assuming one knows what he does.
The driver stage in your 1st diagram can be designed as a linear amplifier if you assume some resistive load, but start by finding what the output stage needs as input to generate the wanted power. Find the needed input peak current and voltage. Then you can develop the driver stage to become able to output them. Designing it as a linear amplifier can give a starting point, but the non-linearity of the output stage occurs also in its input, so you must tune the circuit by making simulations.
Another option is to build one and to make rf measurements. Radio frequency measuring equipment and knowledge is a must. That's far from trivial even at  few MHz.
